# Does the music from mk8dx's Electrodome track appear anywhere else?

Tags: game-music-identification, mario-kart-8-deluxe

When listening to the music from [Electrodome](https://soundcloud.com/user-675036643/mario-kart-8-deluxe-ost-2), I felt like I had heard it before somewhere in the Mario franchise, but couldn't identify where. Is this just because it fits with the Mario Kart genre, or is it a remix of something else?

Comment: It definitely has motifs of the main Mario Kart 8 theme. But that's really all I'm hearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the Electrodrome theme is an original track [arranged by Shiho Fujii](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8_Original_Soundtrack#Tracklist) for Mario Kart 8. The notes for Electrodome on the [Mario Kart 8 Original Soundtrack](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8_Original_Soundtrack#Tracklist) make no mention of it being a remix or being used in other games.

> Unusually for the series, we used dance music here which fits the atmosphere of the shiny dancefloor featured on this track. Shy Guys and Koopa Troopas dance along to the rhythm while you're playing.
>
> <sub>Source: [Mario Kart 8 Original Soundtrack booklet via Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/File:MK8_OST_Pages_3-4_(EU).jpg)</sub>